# Constructing sequence of random variables whose value goes to $-\infty$ while expectation goes to $\infty$

Tags: probability-theory

I've encountered a problem presented below

> Given a suitable probability space $(\Omega ,\mathscr F , \Bbb P)$, please construct a sequence of random variables ${X_{n}}$ such that$$\lim _{n \to \infty} X_{n}(\omega)=-\infty$$ for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$
>   $$ \lim _{n \to \infty} E(X_{n})=\infty$$

Can someone help me with it? I don't know to to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** With Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$: There are constants $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that  $$X_n(t)=\begin{cases}a_n,&(0\le t\le 1/n),\\b_n,&(1/n<t\le 1)\end{cases}$$works.